# fetchS3 processor is giving error:-The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records. (Service: Amazon s3; Status Code:403)

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-nifi, minio

I have a started minIo server using the below docker compose file, after that I have created a bucket and uploaded few files, I have a nifi template where I have listS3 processor and fetchS3 processor, with lists3 processor I am able to fetch the objects present in s3 bucket, but fetch S3 is not working, getting the error mentioned in title of the post even after giving the same access key and secret key as used in minIO. I am using minio server as an alternate to AWS

[image]

The docker compose file is also mentioned below:-

```
version: "2"
services:
    minio:
        image: minio/minio:RELEASE.2020-12-16T05-05-17Z
        volumes:
            - minio-data1:/data
        ports:
            - "9001:9000"
        environment:
            MINIO_ACCESS_KEY: minio
            MINIO_SECRET_KEY: minio123
        command: minio server /data
volumes:
  minio-data1:

networks:
    default:
       external:
           name: ngp-dev
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) and find out why it often has the opposite effect.

Answer (score 0):

Just give end point url where your local minio server is running.